# Blender internal shadows not rendering

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, light, shadows, lighting

i come back to internal after a long time and I've forgotten many things about it and much has changed, why aren't any shadows rendering in my scene?

here is the file
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7fkkzfq5qG1cGZWVVU4TDlaNjA/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

nevermind i found the answer, was my own mistake

in the compositing texture nodes, i directly connected the color to the output without connecting it to a material node first. smh.